# Lookup tables in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, lookup

I would like to create a lookup table in OCaml. The table will have 7000+ entries that, upon lookup (by int), return a string. What is an appropriate data structure to use for this task? Should the table be externalized from the base code and if so, how does one go about "including" the lookup table to be accessible from his/her program?

Thanks.

Comment: What you mean by "including" here is not clear. Maybe you could give some pseudo-code for what you'd like to do?

Comment: What I mean by "including" is to externalize the data from the code, sort of like a header file. Is this possible with OCaml?

Comment: Still not sure what you mean. OCaml has a separate-compilation system that doesn't require header files. Just make sure the module is in the include path at compile time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the strings are addressed using consecutive integers you could use an array.

Otherwise you can use a hash table (non-functional) or a Map (functional). To get started with the Map try:

```
module Int =
struct
  type t = int
  let compare = compare
end ;;

module IntMap = Map.Make(Int) ;;
```

If the table is too large to store in memory, you could store it in an external database and use bindings to [dbm](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Dbm.html), bdb, [sqlite](http://www.ocaml.info/home/ocaml_sources.html#toc13),...

Comment: If stored in an array (the index IS significant) but in a separate .ml file, how would I could about "including" the file that only contains the look-up table/array?

Answer (score 5):

```
let table : (int,string) Hashtbl.t = Hashtbl.create 8192
```

Answer (score 4):

To store the table in a separate file (e.g. as an array), simply create a file `strings.ml` with the content:

```
let tbl = [|
    "String 0";
    "String 1";
    "String 2";
    ...7000 more...
|]
```

Compile this with:

```
ocamlc -c strings.ml
```

As explained in the [manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual004.html#toc17), this defines a module `Strings` that other Ocaml modules can reference. For example, you can start a toplevel:

```
ocaml strings.cmo
```

And lookup a string by accessing a particular position in the array:

```
Strings.tbl.(1234) ;;
```

Comment: With this logic I've created two files: foo.ml and bar.ml. bar.ml contains the line "let x = [|3;2;1|];;" and foo.ml contains "open bar;; " which seems to incur a compiler error after running ocamlc -c bar.ml then ocamlc -o foo foo.ml . What's wrong here?

Comment: Do `open Bar;;`: module names start with a capital. `ocamlc` without `-c` also does linking: you provide all files that need to be linked in: `ocamlc -o foo bar.cmo foo.ml`